# Invertibility of an element of the form $1+r+r^2+ \cdots+ r^{2005}$ in a ring when $r^n=0$ for some $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is from a practice exam I was working on. In particular this isn't homework.

> Let $R$ be a ring with $1\in R$. Suppose that $r\in R$ satisfies $r^n=0$ for some positive integer $n$. Prove that $s:=1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{2005}$ is invertible in $R$.

**My attempt**: Well I thought of breaking up into two cases. One when $n\leq 2005$ and $n>2005$. I know how to show this in the former case. But for the latter case I've been going around in circles for an hour now. :)

Can anybody give some help here?

As always your comments/answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sum of an invertible and an nilpotent element is invertible.

Comment: $(1+r+r^2+\dots+r^{n-1})(1-r)=1-r^n=1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complete the proof, note that it suffices to show that $1-r^{2006}$ is invertible. Pick $k$ so that $2006k >n$ and then $r^{2006k}=0$.

**Alternate solution.**

**Hint 1**

Let $t= r+r^2+\cdots+r^{2005}$. Show that $t^{n}=0$.

**Hint 2**

$$1+t^{2n+1}=(1+t)(\mbox{junk})$$

**Another solution.**

$$(1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{2005})(1+r^{2006}+r^{2006\cdot 2}+...+r^{2006k})=1+r+r^2+...+r^{2006k+2005}$$

and you are in your first case for $k$ large enough....